# QML app run well from Qt Creator IDE but not from deploy

Tags: qt, deployment, qml, qt5

I write a simple QML app then deploy it. When I launch the app from Qt Creator IDE, it runs well. But when I deploy using `windeployqt.exe`, the app runs not well, there are some flicks when I switch between `Window` screens. This is my code:
`SwitchScreen.pro`:

```
TEMPLATE += app
QT += quick qml
CONFIG += c++11
CONFIG += qtquickcompiler
CONFIG += console
CONFIG+=qml_debug

# The following define makes your compiler emit warnings if you use
# any feature of Qt which as been marked deprecated (the exact warnings
# depend on your compiler). Please consult the documentation of the
# deprecated API in order to know how to port your code away from it.
DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS

# You can also make your code fail to compile if you use deprecated APIs.
# In order to do so, uncomment the following line.
# You can also select to disable deprecated APIs only up to a certain version of Qt.
#DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0

SOURCES += \
        main.cpp

RESOURCES += qml.qrc

# Additional import path used to resolve QML modules in Qt Creator's code model
QML_IMPORT_PATH =

# Additional import path used to resolve QML modules just for Qt Quick Designer
QML_DESIGNER_IMPORT_PATH =

# Default rules for deployment.
qnx: target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
else: unix:!android: target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target

DISTFILES += \
    StartupButton.qml \
    MenuScreen.qml \
    main.qml \
    MenuScreen.qml \
    StartupButton.qml
```

`main.cpp`:

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);

    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));
    if (engine.rootObjects().isEmpty())
        return -1;

    return app.exec();
}
```

`main.qml`:

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3

Window {
    id: root
    visible: true
    visibility: Window.FullScreen
    color: "yellow"

    ColumnLayout {
        spacing: 20
        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
        anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
        anchors.margins: 33
        width: .3 * parent.width

        StartupButton {
            text: "Start"
            onClicked: {
                var component = Qt.createComponent("qrc:/MenuScreen.qml")
                console.log("Component Status:", component.status,
                            component.errorString())
                var window = component.createObject(root)
                window.showFullScreen()
                root.hide()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`MenuScreen.qml`:

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Window 2.11
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3

Window {
    id: menuScreen
    visible: true
    visibility: Window.FullScreen
    modality: Qt.ApplicationModal
    color: "green"

    ColumnLayout {
        spacing: 20
        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
        anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
        anchors.margins: 33
        width: .3 * parent.width

        StartupButton {
            text: "Exit"
            onClicked: {
                menuScreen.hide()
                root.showFullScreen()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`StartupButton.qml`:

```
import QtQuick 2.11
import QtQuick.Controls 2.2
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3

Button {
    padding: 10
    anchors.margins: 55
    Layout.fillWidth: true
    font.pointSize: 30
    font.family: "Times New Roman"
    Layout.preferredHeight: 70
    opacity: .4
    palette {
        button: "black"
        buttonText: "white"
    }
    onHoveredChanged: this.palette.button = hovered ? "white" : "black"
}
```

`qml.qrc`:

```
<RCC>
    <qresource prefix="/">
        <file>main.qml</file>
        <file>StartupButton.qml</file>
        <file>MenuScreen.qml</file>
    </qresource>
</RCC>
```

To deploy: in folder contain my app (SwitchScreen.exe): `windployqt --qmldir <path to project folder> SwitchScreen.exe`

Then run the app and switch between screens by press buttons, the screens switching is not smooth, there are some flicks. I don't know why, please help!

I'm using Qt Creator 4.7 and Qt 5.11 msvc2017 64bit.

**UPDATE:** As hyde suggested. I used `procexp` to examine running programs. This is the output:
SwitchScreen_in_ide.txt:

```
Process: SwitchScreen.exe Pid: 6272

Name    Description Company Name    Path
{AFBF9F1A-8EE8-4C77-AF34-C647E37CA0D9}.1.ver0x000000000000000e.db           C:\Users\mrvii\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Caches\{AFBF9F1A-8EE8-4C77-AF34-C647E37CA0D9}.1.ver0x000000000000000e.db
~FontCache-FontFace.dat         C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\LocalService\AppData\Local\FontCache\~FontCache-FontFace.dat
advapi32.dll    Advanced Windows 32 Base API    Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\System32\advapi32.dll
bcrypt.dll  Windows Cryptographic Primitives Library    Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\System32\bcrypt.dll
bcryptprimitives.dll    Windows Cryptographic Primitives Library    Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\System32\bcryptprimitives.dll
Button.qmlc         D:\TestQt\build-SwitchScreen-Desktop_Qt_5_11_1_MSVC2017_64bit2-Release\release\QtQuick\Controls.2\Button.qmlc
cfgmgr32.dll    Configuration Manager DLL   Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\System32\cfgmgr32.dll
clbcatq.dll COM+ Configuration Catalog  Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\System32\clbcatq.dll
combase.dll Microsoft COM for Windows   Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\System32\combase.dll
CoreMessaging.dll   Microsoft CoreMessaging Dll Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\System32\CoreMessaging.dll
CoreUIComponents.dll    Microsoft Core UI Components Dll    Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\System32\CoreUIComponents.dll
crypt32.dll Crypto API32    Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\System32\crypt32.dll
cryptbase.dll   Base cryptographic API DLL  Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\System32\cryptbase.dll
d3d11.dll   Direct3D 11 Runtime Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\System32\d3d11.dll
d3d9.dll    Direct3D 9 Runtime  Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\System32\d3d9.dll
d3dcompiler_47.dll  Direct3D HLSL Compiler for Redistribution   Microsoft Corporation   D:\TestQt\build-SwitchScreen-Desktop_Qt_5_11_1_MSVC2017_64bit2-Release\release\d3dcompiler_47.dll
DataExchange.dll    Data exchange   Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\System32\DataExchange.dll
dcomp.dll   Microsoft DirectComposition Library Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\System32\dcomp.dll
dnsapi.dll  DNS Client API DLL  Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\System32\dnsapi.dll
dwmapi.dll  Microsoft Desktop Window Manager API    Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\System32\dwmapi.dll
DWrite.dll  Microsoft DirectX Typography Services   Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\System32\DWrite.dll
dxgi.dll    DirectX Graphics Infrastructure Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\System32\dxgi.dll
fltLib.dll  Filter Library  Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\System32\fltLib.dll
gdi32.dll   GDI Client DLL  Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\System32\gdi32.dll
gdi32full.dll   GDI Client DLL  Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\System32\gdi32full.dll
igd10iumd64.dll User Mode Driver for Intel(R) Graphics Technology   Intel Corporation   C:\Windows\System32\igd10iumd64.dll
igdusc64.dll    Unified Shader Compiler for Intel(R) Graphics Accelerator   Intel Corporation   C:\Windows\System32\igdusc64.dll
imm32.dll   Multi-User Windows IMM32 API Client DLL Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\System32\imm32.dll
IPHLPAPI.DLL    IP Helper API   Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\System32\IPHLPAPI.DLL
kernel.appcore.dll  AppModel API Host   Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\System32\kernel.appcore.dll
kernel32.dll    Windows NT BASE API Client DLL  Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\System32\kernel32.dll
KernelBase.dll  Windows NT BASE API Client DLL  Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\System32\KernelBase.dll
KernelBase.dll.mui  Windows NT BASE API Client DLL  Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\System32\en-US\KernelBase.dll.mui
libEGL.dll          D:\TestQt\build-SwitchScreen-Desktop_Qt_5_11_1_MSVC2017_64bit2-Release\release\libEGL.dll
libGLESV2.dll           D:\TestQt\build-SwitchScreen-Desktop_Qt_5_11_1_MSVC2017_64bit2-Release\release\libGLESV2.dll
locale.nls          C:\Windows\System32\locale.nls
mpr.dll Multiple Provider Router DLL    Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\System32\mpr.dll
msasn1.dll  ASN.1 Runtime APIs  Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\System32\msasn1.dll
msctf.dll   MSCTF Server DLL    Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\System32\msctf.dll
msvcp_win.dll   Microsoft® C Runtime Library    Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\System32\msvcp_win.dll
msvcp140.dll    Microsoft® C Runtime Library    Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\System32\msvcp140.dll
msvcrt.dll  Windows NT CRT DLL  Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\System32\msvcrt.dll
ncrypt.dll  Windows NCrypt Router   Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\System32\ncrypt.dll
netapi32.dll    Net Win32 API DLL   Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\System32\netapi32.dll
netutils.dll    Net Win32 API Helpers DLL   Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\System32\netutils.dll
nsi.dll NSI User-mode interface DLL Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\System32\nsi.dll
ntasn1.dll  Microsoft ASN.1 API Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\System32\ntasn1.dll
ntdll.dll   NT Layer DLL    Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll
ntmarta.dll Windows NT MARTA provider   Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\System32\ntmarta.dll
ole32.dll   Microsoft OLE for Windows   Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\System32\ole32.dll
oleaut32.dll    OLEAUT32.DLL    Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\System32\oleaut32.dll
powrprof.dll    Power Profile Helper DLL    Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\System32\powrprof.dll
profapi.dll User Profile Basic API  Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\System32\profapi.dll
propsys.dll Microsoft Property System   Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\System32\propsys.dll
qquicklayoutsplugin.dll C++ Application Development Framework   The Qt Company Ltd. D:\TestQt\build-SwitchScreen-Desktop_Qt_5_11_1_MSVC2017_64bit2-Release\release\QtQuick\Layouts\qquicklayoutsplugin.dll
Qt5Core.dll C++ Application Development Framework   The Qt Company Ltd. D:\TestQt\build-SwitchScreen-Desktop_Qt_5_11_1_MSVC2017_64bit2-Release\release\Qt5Core.dll
Qt5Gui.dll  C++ Application Development Framework   The Qt Company Ltd. D:\TestQt\build-SwitchScreen-Desktop_Qt_5_11_1_MSVC2017_64bit2-Release\release\Qt5Gui.dll
Qt5Network.dll  C++ Application Development Framework   The Qt Company Ltd. D:\TestQt\build-SwitchScreen-Desktop_Qt_5_11_1_MSVC2017_64bit2-Release\release\Qt5Network.dll
Qt5Qml.dll  C++ Application Development Framework   The Qt Company Ltd. D:\TestQt\build-SwitchScreen-Desktop_Qt_5_11_1_MSVC2017_64bit2-Release\release\Qt5Qml.dll
Qt5Quick.dll    C++ Application Development Framework   The Qt Company Ltd. D:\TestQt\build-SwitchScreen-Desktop_Qt_5_11_1_MSVC2017_64bit2-Release\release\Qt5Quick.dll
Qt5QuickControls2.dll   C++ Application Development Framework   The Qt Company Ltd. D:\TestQt\build-SwitchScreen-Desktop_Qt_5_11_1_MSVC2017_64bit2-Release\release\Qt5QuickControls2.dll
Qt5QuickTemplates2.dll  C++ Application Development Framework   The Qt Company Ltd. D:\TestQt\build-SwitchScreen-Desktop_Qt_5_11_1_MSVC2017_64bit2-Release\release\Qt5QuickTemplates2.dll
qtquick2plugin.dll  C++ Application Development Framework   The Qt Company Ltd. D:\TestQt\build-SwitchScreen-Desktop_Qt_5_11_1_MSVC2017_64bit2-Release\release\QtQuick.2\qtquick2plugin.dll
qtquickcontrols2plugin.dll  C++ Application Development Framework   The Qt Company Ltd. D:\TestQt\build-SwitchScreen-Desktop_Qt_5_11_1_MSVC2017_64bit2-Release\release\QtQuick\Controls.2\qtquickcontrols2plugin.dll
qtquicktemplates2plugin.dll C++ Application Development Framework   The Qt Company Ltd. D:\TestQt\build-SwitchScreen-Desktop_Qt_5_11_1_MSVC2017_64bit2-Release\release\QtQuick\Templates.2\qtquicktemplates2plugin.dll
qwindows.dll    C++ Application Development Framework   The Qt Company Ltd. D:\TestQt\build-SwitchScreen-Desktop_Qt_5_11_1_MSVC2017_64bit2-Release\release\platforms\qwindows.dll
R00000000000d.clb           C:\Windows\Registration\R00000000000d.clb
rmclient.dll    Resource Manager Client Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\System32\rmclient.dll
rpcrt4.dll  Remote Procedure Call Runtime   Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\System32\rpcrt4.dll
sechost.dll Host for SCM/SDDL/LSA Lookup APIs   Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\System32\sechost.dll
SHCore.dll  SHCORE  Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\System32\SHCore.dll
shell32.dll Windows Shell Common Dll    Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\System32\shell32.dll
shlwapi.dll Shell Light-weight Utility Library  Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\System32\shlwapi.dll
SortDefault.nls         C:\Windows\Globalization\Sorting\SortDefault.nls
srvcli.dll  Server Service Client DLL   Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\System32\srvcli.dll
SwitchScreen.exe            D:\TestQt\build-SwitchScreen-Desktop_Qt_5_11_1_MSVC2017_64bit2-Release\release\SwitchScreen.exe
TextInputFramework.dll  "TextInputFramework.DYNLINK"    Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\System32\TextInputFramework.dll
twinapi.appcore.dll twinapi.appcore Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\System32\twinapi.appcore.dll
ucrtbase.dll    Microsoft® C Runtime Library    Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\System32\ucrtbase.dll
user32.dll  Multi-User Windows USER API Client DLL  Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\System32\user32.dll
user32.dll.mui  Multi-User Windows USER API Client DLL  Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\System32\en-US\user32.dll.mui
userenv.dll Userenv Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\System32\userenv.dll
uxtheme.dll Microsoft UxTheme Library   Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\System32\uxtheme.dll
vcruntime140.dll    Microsoft® C Runtime Library    Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\System32\vcruntime140.dll
version.dll Version Checking and File Installation Libraries    Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\System32\version.dll
win32u.dll  Win32u  Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\System32\win32u.dll
windowplugin.dll    C++ Application Development Framework   The Qt Company Ltd. D:\TestQt\build-SwitchScreen-Desktop_Qt_5_11_1_MSVC2017_64bit2-Release\release\QtQuick\Window.2\windowplugin.dll
windows.storage.dll Microsoft WinRT Storage API Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\System32\windows.storage.dll
winmm.dll   MCI API DLL Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\System32\winmm.dll
winmmbase.dll   Base Multimedia Extension API DLL   Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\System32\winmmbase.dll
WinTypes.dll    Windows Base Types DLL  Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\System32\WinTypes.dll
ws2_32.dll  Windows Socket 2.0 32-Bit DLL   Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\System32\ws2_32.dll
```

SwitchScreen_out_ide.txt:

```
Process: SwitchScreen.exe Pid: 14824

Name    Description Company Name    Path
{AFBF9F1A-8EE8-4C77-AF34-C647E37CA0D9}.1.ver0x000000000000000e.db           C:\Users\mrvii\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Caches\{AFBF9F1A-8EE8-4C77-AF34-C647E37CA0D9}.1.ver0x000000000000000e.db
~FontCache-FontFace.dat         C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\LocalService\AppData\Local\FontCache\~FontCache-FontFace.dat
advapi32.dll    Advanced Windows 32 Base API    Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\System32\advapi32.dll
bcryptprimitives.dll    Windows Cryptographic Primitives Library    Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\System32\bcryptprimitives.dll
Button.qmlc         D:\TestQt\deploy_switchscreen\QtQuick\Controls.2\Button.qmlc
cfgmgr32.dll    Configuration Manager DLL   Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\System32\cfgmgr32.dll
clbcatq.dll COM+ Configuration Catalog  Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\System32\clbcatq.dll
combase.dll Microsoft COM for Windows   Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\System32\combase.dll
CoreMessaging.dll   Microsoft CoreMessaging Dll Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\System32\CoreMessaging.dll
CoreUIComponents.dll    Microsoft Core UI Components Dll    Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\System32\CoreUIComponents.dll
crypt32.dll Crypto API32    Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\System32\crypt32.dll
cryptbase.dll   Base cryptographic API DLL  Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\System32\cryptbase.dll
d3d11.dll   Direct3D 11 Runtime Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\System32\d3d11.dll
d3d9.dll    Direct3D 9 Runtime  Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\System32\d3d9.dll
DataExchange.dll    Data exchange   Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\System32\DataExchange.dll
dcomp.dll   Microsoft DirectComposition Library Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\System32\dcomp.dll
dnsapi.dll  DNS Client API DLL  Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\System32\dnsapi.dll
dwmapi.dll  Microsoft Desktop Window Manager API    Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\System32\dwmapi.dll
DWrite.dll  Microsoft DirectX Typography Services   Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\System32\DWrite.dll
dxgi.dll    DirectX Graphics Infrastructure Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\System32\dxgi.dll
fltLib.dll  Filter Library  Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\System32\fltLib.dll
gdi32.dll   GDI Client DLL  Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\System32\gdi32.dll
gdi32full.dll   GDI Client DLL  Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\System32\gdi32full.dll
glu32.dll   OpenGL Utility Library DLL  Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\System32\glu32.dll
ig8icd64.dll    OpenGL(R) Driver for Intel(R) Graphics Accelerator  Intel Corporation   C:\Windows\System32\ig8icd64.dll
igdusc64.dll    Unified Shader Compiler for Intel(R) Graphics Accelerator   Intel Corporation   C:\Windows\System32\igdusc64.dll
imm32.dll   Multi-User Windows IMM32 API Client DLL Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\System32\imm32.dll
IPHLPAPI.DLL    IP Helper API   Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\System32\IPHLPAPI.DLL
kernel.appcore.dll  AppModel API Host   Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\System32\kernel.appcore.dll
kernel32.dll    Windows NT BASE API Client DLL  Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\System32\kernel32.dll
KernelBase.dll  Windows NT BASE API Client DLL  Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\System32\KernelBase.dll
KernelBase.dll.mui  Windows NT BASE API Client DLL  Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\System32\en-US\KernelBase.dll.mui
locale.nls          C:\Windows\System32\locale.nls
mpr.dll Multiple Provider Router DLL    Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\System32\mpr.dll
msasn1.dll  ASN.1 Runtime APIs  Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\System32\msasn1.dll
msctf.dll   MSCTF Server DLL    Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\System32\msctf.dll
msvcp_win.dll   Microsoft® C Runtime Library    Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\System32\msvcp_win.dll
msvcp140.dll    Microsoft® C Runtime Library    Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\System32\msvcp140.dll
msvcrt.dll  Windows NT CRT DLL  Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\System32\msvcrt.dll
netapi32.dll    Net Win32 API DLL   Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\System32\netapi32.dll
netutils.dll    Net Win32 API Helpers DLL   Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\System32\netutils.dll
nsi.dll NSI User-mode interface DLL Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\System32\nsi.dll
ntdll.dll   NT Layer DLL    Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll
ntmarta.dll Windows NT MARTA provider   Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\System32\ntmarta.dll
ole32.dll   Microsoft OLE for Windows   Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\System32\ole32.dll
oleaut32.dll    OLEAUT32.DLL    Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\System32\oleaut32.dll
opengl32.dll    OpenGL Client DLL   Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\System32\opengl32.dll
powrprof.dll    Power Profile Helper DLL    Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\System32\powrprof.dll
profapi.dll User Profile Basic API  Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\System32\profapi.dll
propsys.dll Microsoft Property System   Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\System32\propsys.dll
qquicklayoutsplugin.dll C++ Application Development Framework   The Qt Company Ltd. D:\TestQt\deploy_switchscreen\QtQuick\Layouts\qquicklayoutsplugin.dll
Qt5Core.dll C++ Application Development Framework   The Qt Company Ltd. D:\TestQt\deploy_switchscreen\Qt5Core.dll
Qt5Gui.dll  C++ Application Development Framework   The Qt Company Ltd. D:\TestQt\deploy_switchscreen\Qt5Gui.dll
Qt5Network.dll  C++ Application Development Framework   The Qt Company Ltd. D:\TestQt\deploy_switchscreen\Qt5Network.dll
Qt5Qml.dll  C++ Application Development Framework   The Qt Company Ltd. D:\TestQt\deploy_switchscreen\Qt5Qml.dll
Qt5Quick.dll    C++ Application Development Framework   The Qt Company Ltd. D:\TestQt\deploy_switchscreen\Qt5Quick.dll
Qt5QuickControls2.dll   C++ Application Development Framework   The Qt Company Ltd. D:\TestQt\deploy_switchscreen\Qt5QuickControls2.dll
Qt5QuickTemplates2.dll  C++ Application Development Framework   The Qt Company Ltd. D:\TestQt\deploy_switchscreen\Qt5QuickTemplates2.dll
qtquick2plugin.dll  C++ Application Development Framework   The Qt Company Ltd. D:\TestQt\deploy_switchscreen\QtQuick.2\qtquick2plugin.dll
qtquickcontrols2plugin.dll  C++ Application Development Framework   The Qt Company Ltd. D:\TestQt\deploy_switchscreen\QtQuick\Controls.2\qtquickcontrols2plugin.dll
qtquicktemplates2plugin.dll C++ Application Development Framework   The Qt Company Ltd. D:\TestQt\deploy_switchscreen\QtQuick\Templates.2\qtquicktemplates2plugin.dll
qwindows.dll    C++ Application Development Framework   The Qt Company Ltd. D:\TestQt\deploy_switchscreen\platforms\qwindows.dll
R00000000000d.clb           C:\Windows\Registration\R00000000000d.clb
rmclient.dll    Resource Manager Client Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\System32\rmclient.dll
rpcrt4.dll  Remote Procedure Call Runtime   Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\System32\rpcrt4.dll
sechost.dll Host for SCM/SDDL/LSA Lookup APIs   Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\System32\sechost.dll
SHCore.dll  SHCORE  Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\System32\SHCore.dll
shell32.dll Windows Shell Common Dll    Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\System32\shell32.dll
shlwapi.dll Shell Light-weight Utility Library  Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\System32\shlwapi.dll
SortDefault.nls         C:\Windows\Globalization\Sorting\SortDefault.nls
srvcli.dll  Server Service Client DLL   Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\System32\srvcli.dll
SwitchScreen.exe            D:\TestQt\deploy_switchscreen\SwitchScreen.exe
TextInputFramework.dll  "TextInputFramework.DYNLINK"    Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\System32\TextInputFramework.dll
twinapi.appcore.dll twinapi.appcore Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\System32\twinapi.appcore.dll
ucrtbase.dll    Microsoft® C Runtime Library    Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\System32\ucrtbase.dll
user32.dll  Multi-User Windows USER API Client DLL  Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\System32\user32.dll
user32.dll.mui  Multi-User Windows USER API Client DLL  Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\System32\en-US\user32.dll.mui
userenv.dll Userenv Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\System32\userenv.dll
uxtheme.dll Microsoft UxTheme Library   Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\System32\uxtheme.dll
vcruntime140.dll    Microsoft® C Runtime Library    Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\System32\vcruntime140.dll
version.dll Version Checking and File Installation Libraries    Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\System32\version.dll
win32u.dll  Win32u  Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\System32\win32u.dll
windowplugin.dll    C++ Application Development Framework   The Qt Company Ltd. D:\TestQt\deploy_switchscreen\QtQuick\Window.2\windowplugin.dll
windows.storage.dll Microsoft WinRT Storage API Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\System32\windows.storage.dll
winmm.dll   MCI API DLL Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\System32\winmm.dll
winmmbase.dll   Base Multimedia Extension API DLL   Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\System32\winmmbase.dll
WinTypes.dll    Windows Base Types DLL  Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\System32\WinTypes.dll
ws2_32.dll  Windows Socket 2.0 32-Bit DLL   Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\System32\ws2_32.dll
wtsapi32.dll    Windows Remote Desktop Session Host Server SDK APIs Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\System32\wtsapi32.dll
```

Then I compare those outputs and see those differences:
In ide:

```
bcrypt.dll  Windows Cryptographic Primitives Library    Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\System32\bcrypt.dll    
d3dcompiler_47.dll  Direct3D HLSL Compiler for Redistribution   Microsoft Corporation   D:\TestQt\build-SwitchScreen-Desktop_Qt_5_11_1_MSVC2017_64bit2-Release\release\d3dcompiler_47.dll    
igd10iumd64.dll User Mode Driver for Intel(R) Graphics Technology   Intel Corporation   C:\Windows\System32\igd10iumd64.dll
libEGL.dll          D:\TestQt\build-SwitchScreen-Desktop_Qt_5_11_1_MSVC2017_64bit2-Release\release\libEGL.dll
libGLESV2.dll           D:\TestQt\build-SwitchScreen-Desktop_Qt_5_11_1_MSVC2017_64bit2-Release\release\libGLESV2.dll    
ncrypt.dll  Windows NCrypt Router   Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\System32\ncrypt.dll    
ntasn1.dll  Microsoft ASN.1 API Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\System32\ntasn1.dll
```

out ide:

```
glu32.dll   OpenGL Utility Library DLL  Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\System32\glu32.dll
ig8icd64.dll    OpenGL(R) Driver for Intel(R) Graphics Accelerator  Intel Corporation   C:\Windows\System32\ig8icd64.dll    
opengl32.dll    OpenGL Client DLL   Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\System32\opengl32.dll    
wtsapi32.dll    Windows Remote Desktop Session Host Server SDK APIs Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\System32\wtsapi32.dll
```

Can I conclude that the app runs outside ide used wrong graphics backend? And how to force it to use the right graphics backend. As I see, in the deployment folder, there are some files: `libEGL.dll`, `libGLESV2.dll`. Thanks!

Comment: You might check which .dll files the program has open in different cases. use *procexp.exe* (Google that) to examine running programs for files they have open. I am suspecting they may end up using different platform plugin, or fail to choose the right graphics backend (there were Angle and OpenGL options some time ago, don't know the status right now).

Comment: I'm still investigating this. Current the issue was occurred from IDE too. I used Dependendcy walker(Menu > Profile > Start Profiling) to show some log then saw some strange log like: `onecore\windows\core\console\open\src\host\srvinit.cpp(411)\conhost.exe!00007FF733BFC372: (caller: 00007FF733BF8CD9) ReturnHr(7) tid(1678) 80070032 The request is not supported.`

Comment: Note that *depends.exe* will not show any dynamically loaded .dlls, AKA plugins. So it does not show the platform plugin of Qt, used by all Qt apps, for example. So it is a complementary tool, you also need *procexp.exe*.

Comment: I have the same [issue] (https://forum.qt.io/topic/53771/qml-applicationwindow-fullscreen-issues/3) . But their solution have not resolve mine.